# Django-models: use field from foreign key

Tags: python, django, django-uploads

I'm working on an image gallery project in DJango, just for the sake of it. And well, I have a class named `Gallery` and a class named `ImageGallery`.

The class named gallery would look like this:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
 gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name="parent_gallery")
 title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 folder = models.CharField(max_length=200) # ex: images/galleries/slugify(self.title)

class ImageGallery(models.Model):
 gallery = models.ForeignKey(Gallery, related_name="parent_gallery")
 title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
 image = models.ImageField(upload_to=self.gallery.folder)
```

Well, the last line of code is what I want to know if its possible or any other fine replacement for it.

In the `DJango-admin` I want to be able to add records for the table `ImageGallery` and when selecting the `Gallery` I would like to use, the images to be saved to the folder specified in `gallery.folder` field.

What's the best way to go around this? I haven't completed writing the two classes but I doubt they're gonna work like this. Thank you in advance. :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [FileField.upload_to](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to) is defined as follows

> This attribute provides a way of setting the upload directory and file
>   name, and can be set in two ways. In both cases, the value is passed
>   to the Storage.save() method. ... upload_to may also be a callable,
>   such as a function. This will be called to obtain the upload path,
>   including the filename. This callable must accept two arguments and
>   return a Unix-style path (with forward slashes) to be passed along to
>   the storage system. The two arguments are:

But `self.gallery.folder` isn't a callable. What you need is to setup a function along the lines given in that example

```
def get_upload_path(instance, filename):
    return '{0}/{1}'.format(instance.gallery.folder, filename)
```

And your model will change to

```
image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_upload_path)
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that. That aside, the way to go is pretty awesome. yay for Django!