# dynamically upload django FileField/ImageField

Tags: django, django-models

I am working on an application that has a record of movies and actors. I actors to have a lot of images and/or a lot of videos which should have the user's or movie id as part of the file path. I have decided to use a m2m relationship since the image or video file could belong to either a person or a movie but I'm stuck cause I'm not sure of how to approach this problem. Here is a sample of my image class. The video class is more or less the same.

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    photo = models.ImageField(upload_to=file_path)
    actors = models.ManyToManyField(
        'Actor',
        related_name='images'
    )
    movies= models.ManyToManyField(
        'Movie',
        related_name='images',
    )
```

But this way I have no way of storing actor or movie id as part of the file path
I thought of using a **ForeignKey** relationship instead of a m2m relationship but I thought that would not be accurate as not all Image objects would have an actor and Movie associated to it. I believe the relationship would be an **either or** relationship. Is there another way I could approach this problem?

Comment: Why does it matter what the file path is?

Comment: I want to use a pattern to store the files. Considering they could be a lot, it'd be nice to do that than just store in random locations

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django-models: use field from foreign key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264590/django-models-use-field-from-foreign-key)